# Inject partial into DOM on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have data stored in the "code" column of my "version" model. On the show page, I want to inject that data into the html of `#canvas` when the page loads. When the page loads though, there is no content in `#canvas`.

/ui.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @version, remote: true do |f| %>       
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :code, id: "version-content" %>
  <%= f.submit "Save Version", id: "submit-version" %>
<% end %>
```

versions_controller.rb

```
def create
  @version = Version.new(creation_params)

  if @version.save
    flash[:success] = "Version saved."
    redirect_to @version
  else
    render :new
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

versions/create.js.erb

```
$('#canvas').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'versions/code')).html_safe %>");
```

versions/_code.html.erb

```
<%= @version.code %>
```

versions/show.html.erb

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: lol I guess that might help. I edited my question. Basically, the content is not being injected for some reason. The #canvas div is empty when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do what you want?
Now this code will render your `show.js.erb` when you access like /:controller/show.js and I believe it's not render html variant. So your js haven't where to insert content.
If you want render partial within partial add this to partial (guess /views/show.html.erb)

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/code' %>
```

It's best practice to use shared folder if you render partial in couple views. Be sure you have _code.html.erb in share folder of views directory.

Comment: I tried that but the data consists of html. All the "<" and ">" are saving as "&lt;" and "&gt;". So when I output them, the html gets outputted as a bunch of words, rather than html. So maybe I need to prevent rails from converting the "<" and ">" into lt and gt signs?

Comment: use raw <%= raw @instant.html_content %> where you need html not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

How do you access the show action? Does JS get triggered?

Does your link to the show action include `remote: true`?
or

Where is the onload function in JS, if no remote link?

`show.js.erb`gets only triggered, if the request is per Javascript!

For forms:

```
<%= form_for @something, remote: true do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

**Update versions_controller.rb:**

```
def create
  if @version.save

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @version }
      format.js
    end

  else
  ... 
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I'm accessing the page via a form on /demo. You submit the form, the form creates a new version in the db and the create action redirects you to the version show page.

Comment: does your form helper include `remote: true`?

Comment: I added some info in my answer.

Comment: I added remote true but it still doesn't work. Because the remote true is on the create action, do I need to move the JS to the create action? So it would be create.js.erb instead of show.js.erb

Comment: Yes the js file has to have the same name as the action.

Comment: The form is not submitting now because I set it to remote true. Do I need to submit it with JQuery?

Comment: You can choose between `remote`and jQuery in Rails. Can you show your form action?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49752/discussion-between-crispychicken-and-moppy)